# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::Package::FormatError) package metadata is missing in profile.gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I use OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 First,i have  problem with installing pods and able to find the problem after follow step in this site..the terminal spell the problem out it was ruby v 2.2.2 after I installed it I get new problem when I try to install cocoapods

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods

Password:

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Package::FormatError)
package metadata is missing in profile.gem
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to uninstall and then install again.

```
gem uninstall cocoapods
```

or

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

and then

```
gem install cocoapods
```

or

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Why are you using `sudo`? That is usually not necessary. Did the other stackoverflow post mention doing that.

Comment: I try it before..nothing change